# Regular Expression to find all Email Matches help for C# application

Tags: c#, regex

I have an application where I need to parse a string to find all the e-mail addresses in a that string. I am not a regular espression guru by any means and not sure what the differnce is between some expressions. I have found 2 expressions that, apprently, will match all of the e-mail addresses in a string. I cannot get either to work in my C# application. Here are the expressions:

```
/\b([A-Z0-9._%-]+)@([A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})\b/i

^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$
```

Here is an example string:

```
Adam
<mailto:aedwards@domain.com?subject=Your%20prospect%20Search%20-%20ID:
%2011111>  Edwards - Prospect ID: 11111, Ph: (555) 555-5555 
Al
<mailto:Al@anotherdomain.com?subject=Your%20prospect%20Search%20-%20
ID:%20222222>  Grayson - Prospect ID: 222222, Ph: 
Angie
```

Here is the code in c#:

```
var mailReg = new Regex(EmailMatch, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
var matches = mailReg.Matches(theString);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first of your two examples should work if you remove the \b from both ends.  The \b means that it expects a word boundary (a space, end of line, &c.) before and after the email address and this is not present in your case.

(Please do not use your new found powers for evil.)

Comment: `:` and `?` are considered word boundaries, aren't they?

Comment: As per one of the other answers, the expression does not handle subdomains, e.g. example.co.uk, example.co.jp &c.

Comment: No, I have not tried it — the pattern does not have a repeating section for multiple subdomin parts.  It would have to be changed to something like /([A-Z0-9._%-]+)@(([A-Z0-9.-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4})/

Comment: The bottom section of the following link appears to have a set of useful, and more comprehensive, expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: ...and then there is, of course, *the* regex pattern for email addresses: http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/full_regexp.txt

Comment: @Paul: Try it, it works. Since the dot is part of the character class, multiple subdomains are matched just fine. Disadvantage: it matches also `i@...com` - but your new one does so, too. And the OP didn't ask for e-mail *validation*, which is another beast entirely.

Comment: Ah yes, did not notice the dot in there.  Regular Expressions and Perl share the unreadability once written trait.

Comment: `\b` does *not* match whitespace or any other character. It's a zero-width assertion, like the start and end anchors, lookaheads and lookbehinds.  Given that every email addresses has to start and end with a word character, the OP definitely *should* use word boundaries.

Comment: Alan (you didn't use to work with me in 2000 did you?), I did not say that \b *matched* a word character, but that its presence will prevent a match if a word is not preceded/followed by a word boundary such as the start of line, end of line or non-word character.  I suspected that the colon preceding the address was preventing the match.

Comment: Alan, I have run some tests and it seems that the \b does not prevent the match.  Maybe the OP was not including the at symbol (@) before the pattern string so .NET was interpreting the \b as an escape sequence.

Answer (score 3):

The first regex is a Perl object (delimited by slashes). Drop the slashes and the mode modifier (i), and it should work:

```
EmailMatch = @"\b([A-Z0-9._%-]+)@([A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6})\b"
```

Also, .museum is a valid domain, so {2,6} is a bit better.

The second regex only matches entire strings that consist of nothing but an email address.

I would leave the `\b` intact.

Comment: There are `yahoo.co.uk` email addresses

Comment: What's wrong with yahoo.co.uk addresses? They'll be matched, too, since the dot is part of the character class after @. Or what am I not getting?

Comment: @Tim The dot within character class escaped my eyes. I noticed only the escaped dot `\.` - But then again as you mentioned in the other thread, it opens another Pandora's box - luckily the question is not about email validation.

Answer (score 2):

This expression worked: ([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+).([a-zA-Z]{2,5})

Thanks for looking!